# how initialize dynamically inserted data-group to bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

i'm writing a page where there's products and each product belongs to a section, i used bootstrap's data-groups to divide them into sections.

```
   <div class="row mb-5">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle justify-content-center d-flex" data-toggle="buttons" style="flex-wrap: wrap;">

          <label class="btn btn-sm btn-primary active" style="background-color:#DEEFC5; font-family: 'Courier New'; color: #000000;">
            <input type="radio" name="shuffle-filter" value="all" checked="checked" />الكل
          </label>
          @foreach ($sections as $section)

          <label class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="background-color:#DEEFC5; font-family: 'Courier New'; color: #000000;">
            <input type="radio" name="shuffle-filter" value="{{ $section->section }}" />{{ $section->section }}
          </label>

          @endforeach
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr class="hr-text" data-content="">
    <div class="select">
        <select name="slct" id="slct" style="font-family: 'Courier New';">
          <option selected disabled>تصفية</option>
          <option name='1' value="price">الاقل سعراً</option>
          <option name='0' value="price">الأكثر سعراً</option>
          <option name='1' value="created_at">الاحدث</option>
          <option name='0' value="created_at">الأقدم</option>
        </select>
      </div>

    <div id="products" class="row shuffle-wrapper">
      @foreach ($products as $product)

        <div id="duck" class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mb-4 shuffle-item" data-groups="[&quot;{{ $product->section->section }}&quot;]">
            <article class="card shadow">
              @if ($product->isLabeld) 

              <div class="label topleft">
              <p>{{$product->label}}</p>
              <img class="rounded card-img-top" src="{{ $product->img }}" alt="post-thumb">
              </div>

              @else
              <img class="rounded card-img-top" src="{{ $product->img }}" alt="post-thumb">
              @endif

              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title" style="text-align: right;"><a class="text-dark" href="shop/{{$product->id}}">{{ $product->name }}</a>
                </h4>
                <p class="description">{{ $product->discription }}</p>
                <a href="shop/{{$product->id}}" style="display:inline-block; background-color:#000000;" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" ></i></a>
              <h1 class="price_tag">{{ $product->price }}$</h1>
              </div>
            </article>
        </div>

      @endforeach
  </div>
```

as you can see above each sections is given a value and if the product's data-group attribute has the same value they are considered to be in that section. so far it is all working good and as expected.
However, i have a sorting function written with jquery that empties the products div and then takes sorted products from the db and put them in view them using ajax, and once that's done since the elements are added dynamically the data-group attribute is not initialized and therefore they are not linked to the sections.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){


    $(document).on('change', '#slct', function(e){
      var term = String($('#slct').val());
      var order = String($('#slct').find('option:selected').attr("name"));

      const myUrlWithParams = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8001/search");
      myUrlWithParams.searchParams.append("term", term);
      myUrlWithParams.searchParams.append("order", order);

      fetchRecords(myUrlWithParams);

    });
  });

  function fetchRecords(url){
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response){

        $('#products').empty(); 
        $('#products').html(response.html);  

        $("body #duck").bootstrapToggle('destroy');              
        $("body #duck").bootstrapToggle();

      }
    });
  }
  </script>
```

i tried to initialize it bootstrapToggle() but it does not work.

does anybody have an idea how can i re-initialize the data-group attribute so the sections can identify them?

Comment: Maybe unrelated to the solution but you're using the id="duck" multiple times as you write it in a foreach loop. ids have to be unique. Can you use a class instead?

Comment: thanks for reminding me, jquery is not my strongest suite